# two different command line argument in c

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

i want to parse two different command line argument such that :

file -f something -o something

i found some code on internet and i changed it but i cannot parse both of them.

```
int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *fvalue = NULL;
  char *ovalue = NULL;
  int index;
  int c;

  opterr = 0;
  while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "fo:")) != -1)
    switch (c)
      {
      case 'f':
        fvalue = optarg;
        break;
      case 'o':
        ovalue = optarg;
        break;
      default:
        abort ();
      }
  printf ("fvalue = %s, ovalue = %s\n",
          fvalue, ovalue);

  for (index = optind; index < argc; index++)
    printf ("Non-option argument %s\n", argv[index]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not access the arguments from argv? argv[2] will hold something1 and argv[4] something2...

Comment: i dont know how to do that

Comment: argv is an array of strings that holds all the arguments you pass during command line execute(including program name). So in your case when you run "file -f something -o something", argv[0] will be "file", argv[1] will be "-f" etc. And if you want to print it all you got to do is go like printf("%s",argv[1]) and "-f" will show up. Hope I helped!

Comment: thank you so much @TheDillo i solved the problem just the below way but what i learned from you is really nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your optstring is wrong, it must be

```
while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "f:o:")) != -1)
```

the colon means that the option requires an argument.